# Can't Reinstall Solarwinds 9.2 after installing 10.9.1 Trial version

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, monitoring

I am having an issue I am hoping someone can help me with. I own a copy of an older version of solarwinds 9.2, I decided I wanted to give the new solarwinds version a try so I decided to download it. Solarwinds doesn't allow concurrent installations so I had to remove version 9.2 to install the 10.9.1 evaluation version. Now that my evaluation period has expired I want to go back to my licensed copy, although it wont let me reinstall my original version because it is still showing that I have a newer version installed. I tried removing all leftover bits and used revo to uninstall it and still nothing. I have no idea how to get by this. I put in a support request although I am wondering if anyone here has any information on getting around this.

Comment: Reimage the machine.  That'll get rid of any pesky leftover bits from the newer trial version.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions.

1. Restore from a backup you made before you upgraded to the eval version. (Best option!)
2. Reimage the machine, as HopelessN00b suggested.
3. Take the opportunity to install 9.2 on a fresh new server/fresh new VM!

If you're absolutely unable to do any of those, your only recourse is to delete all data directories and registry keys related to the product and roll the database back to a version before the upgrade.  That's not guaranteed, and is annoying, but it might work.

Comment: Based on the Windows 7 tag, I assumed this was installed on a Windows 7 machine.  Could be wrong, and that's kinda weird, but that's how it looks to me (so unlikely to have backups, but easier/quicker to reimage).